# TokuDB Concurrent Inserts cause lock timeouts

Tags: mysql, innodb, tokudb

I have concurrent batch inserts with around 1000 records per batch, on a TokuDB 7.5. 
Each batch update is done within a single transaction. The table contains around 100 million records too.

The issue is that it throws the following exception time to time.

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
>   transaction

The transaction isolation level used is Repeatable_Read and I read in an article that using Repeatable_Read would result in gap locks for SELECT queries.

But at the moment we have only INSERTS.

Could this lock timeout be due to gap locks and if so how does concurrent INSERTS get affected by gap locks?

**The schema**

```
 CREATE TABLE `message` (
 `id`                   BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `message_id`           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 `sent_time`            TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
 `type_id`              TINYINT(4)  NOT NULL,
 `correlation_id`       BIGINT(20)  NOT NULL,
 `origination_address`  VARCHAR(16)    NOT NULL,
 `destination_address`  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 `created_time`         TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  UNIQUE KEY (`message_id`,`sent_time`, `type_id`, `correlation_id`),
  KEY `OA` (`origination_address`),
  KEY `DA` (`destination_address`)
```

)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Also, what order are the records in?  (As in, sorted on `PRIMARY KEY` or ...)

Comment: I have updated question with the schema.

Comment: Also, what order are the records in the input stream?  Is the computer I/O bound when the timeout occurs?

Comment: What do you mean by the order of record ? I didn't quite get that. It wasn't IO bound at the time. I don't quite remember but the CPU utilization was around 60% and disk writes were not that high.

Comment: If the input data is sorted by (`message_id`,`sent_time`, `type_id`, `correlation_id`), it will _probably_ load faster.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout%;`